# Trying to print a label in Angular and keep its formatting

Tags: javascript, angular

I have been trying for a couple of weeks now to print a label using angular.  I am able to get the label to print with no issues.  The issue is it loses the formatting of the label in the preview print and also printing.  I have tried a lot of the code floating around and no matter which function I run the HTML through I get the same results. I have also tried a combo of the .ts, .html, and scss.component.  The code is below on what is working now to the point it needs to print.  Also to note this is a modal pop up.

```js
   printDiv(): void {
    var divContents = document.getElementById("GFG").innerHTML;
    var a = window.open('', '', 'height=500, width=500');
    a.document.write('<html>');
    a.document.write('<body > <h1>Div contents are <br>');
    a.document.write(divContents);
    a.document.write('</body></html>');
    a.document.close();
    a.print();
}
```

```css
@media print {
    body * {
      visibility: hidden;
    }
    #section-to-print, #section-to-print * {
      visibility: visible;
    }
    #section-to-print {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div  id="GFG" class="divTable">
    <div class="divTableBody">
    <div class="divTableRow">
    <div class="divTableCell">
        <br />
        <scl-ngx-qrcode [text]="qrCodeString" [options]="options"></scl-ngx-qrcode>
        <br />
    </div>
    <div class="divTableCell">
        <h4 class="text-center">COC: 23456</h4>
        <div>{{ CompanyName }}</div>
        <div>{{ AddressLine1 }}</div>
        <div>{{ AddressLine2 }}</div>
        <div>{{ City }}, {{ PostalCode }}</div>
        <div>{{ PhoneNumber }}
        <div>{{ PrjCode }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
    <div class="divTableCell">
        <h1 class="display-2 text-center">RUSH</h1>
        <br/>
        Container _____ of _____
        <br/>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableCell">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <button (click)="printDiv()">Print Label(s)</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Css classes aren't in the new window document's scope. To it (even with innerHTML) class `divTable` is just nowhere to be found. Seems like your not attaching any stylesheets either for the new document. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43110489/15439733

```js
a.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">';
```

Other option would be to attach styling as you create the document which could be even more simpler than attaching a style sheet. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53864968/15439733

---

Here is a working example how to attach a stylesheet on `write` to document.

https://jsfiddle.net/Nurech/gn76wd1x/2/

For more information about this: https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/print-css-with-angular#adding-a-print-button